# HTML drag and drop OnDrop Ajax event

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have a simple page that uses HTML Drag and Dropable thumbnails created by a MySQLi function. like so

```
    <?php
    include "database_connection.php";
    $query = "SELECT * FROM table where currentZone = 0";
    if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
        /* fetch associative array */
        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
 {      
            echo "<img id='{$row["ID"]}' src='{$row["photoLink"]}.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)' width='75' height='75'>"  ;
        }
        /* free result set */
        mysqli_free_result($result);
    }
     mysqli_close($link);
    ?>
```

In this simple page I have four droppable divs

```
<div id="1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="3" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<div id="4" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
```

I am able to drag each thumbnail into each div back and forth at will.

My question:

Using Ajax, can anyone provide an example of a way to perform an on-drop event to post to a php page where I have my database work?

Example: If I pickup thumbnail-1, and drop it into div-2, can an on-drop event trigger my php code so that I can modify my database to reflect the change from div to div?

I know I could probably do this by pushing the `<img id="">` into an ajax script but after hours of searching I am unable to find sample code proving that it can be done. I am very new with Ajax and I am able to get ajax to work properly with input fields, but cannot find any assistance when using drag/drop events. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated.

edit **

Here is the current code:

script.js

```
function drop(id, event) {
   $.ajax({
        url: "test.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: id,
            event: event
        },
        success: function () {
            console.log('great success');
            return true
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

mainpage.php

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/script.js"></script>
<header class="main-header" role="banner"><center>
  <img src="logo.jpg" height="90" width="400"alt="Banner Image"/></center>
</header>

<script>
function allowDrop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
</script>
</head>
<body>




<div id="1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<?php 
include "database_connection.php";
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////


/* check connection */
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
else
{
}

$query = "SELECT * FROM table where currentZone = 1";

if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {

    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


        echo "<img id='{$row["ID"]}' src='{$row["photoLink"]}.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)' width='75' height='75'>"  ;
    }

    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
 mysqli_close($link);
 /////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
?>

</div>

<div id="2" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)">
<?php
include "database_connection.php";
$query = "SELECT * FROM table where currentZone = 2";
if ($result = mysqli_query($link, $query)) {
    /* fetch associative array */
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {        
        echo "<img id='{$row["ID"]}' src='{$row["photoLink"]}.jpg' draggable='true' ondragstart='drag(event)' width='75' height='75'>"  ;
    }
    /* free result set */
    mysqli_free_result($result);
}
 mysqli_close($link);
?>

</div>
 ?>
```

and the test.php merely connects to the  DB and inserts a junk record.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function drop(id, event) {
   $.ajax({
        url: "do_sql_stuff.php",
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            id: id,
            event: event
        },
        success: function () {
            console.log('great success');
            return true
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Then in your do_sql_stuff.php you can get

```
$event = $_POST['event']; 
 $id   = $_POST['id'];
```

Comment: I'll give it a try. thanks for the info.

Comment: Obviously you need to pass the id into the function <div id="4" ondrop="drop(4, event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> .... I would be loading this with php aswell so you can just pass in a variable

Comment: I was just about to ask that. thanks!

Comment: I am able to get the php page to function properly manually (by visiting the url), but after changing div4 to do what you posted, and putting the function in a script, It does not appear to POST. any ideas on steps I missed?

Comment: added code to question -